What are differences and similarities between 2017 Paranoia (Red Clearance Edition) and 2023 (The All New Shiny Edition) one?
There are two editions of Paranoia you can still buy*:

2017 (Red Clearance Edition)
2023 (The All New Shiny Edition)

They are supposed to be similar and somewhat compatible, but the first one uses cards heavily, while the second one doesn't seem so.
So in what ways they are different? And in what ways they're compatible? For example, if one would want to use cards with 2023, would it work? Would missions still be compatible?
Previous comparison can be found here: What are the differences between Paranoia XP/25th Anniversary and Paranoia 2017?

Links to publisher's shop are not to endorse products, just to clearly identify them. I am not associated with the publisher, I just wonder if and what to buy.
* Buy new, from the publisher, at the time of writing in summer 2024

I'm away from my books right now, but I believe in the introduction it says the biggest difference is that the new edition is perfect in every way, while the previous edition (by largely the same authors) was merely excellent.

@aantia I wonder if they resolved https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133577/10642 - but that would be a separate question I guess.

Helpfully, there is a section titled 'Converting RCE [Red Clearance Edition] Content to PPE [Paranoia Perfect Edition]', starting on page 134. If you want to convert an ongoing campaign, start there. I will quote from that quite heavily. I've skipped stuff that seems really trivial, like 'illegal gear goes in a particular spot on your character sheet'.
Things that did not change

Stats, Skills and their ratings
Clone and Loyalty
The core rules about NODEs (dice pools)
Wounds and Health Boxes
Treason Stars (except they're referred to as 'flags' a lot, e.g. 'Gain the Citizen-of-interest' flag)
GMs still do not roll
The missions are largely compatible - some mechanics have been removed (e.g. NPC stats) but they can be run as-is if you like (see the last section below)
Character creation is mostly the same - it's still an exercise in screwing over the other players, and still has unresolved questions around edge cases


Things that did change
Troubleshooters

All PCs now have a Service Group
Personality adjectives are gone
PCs now have Violence and Treason Buttons (i.e. less nuanced personalities, suitable for violent, drugged-up Reds)
XP points can't be used to improve stats or skills; now we have Upgrade Points for that
All PCs start with Guns +2 - nobody can choose a different Guns rating in character creation
PCs start with 200 XP points, so the GM can take them away

NPCs
NPCs no longer have any stats. The GM is told to set difficulties as they see fit (remember, players do all the dice rolling).
The Cards
The new edition does not include the cards, but there are rules for using them.
Quote: "So here is our Official Famous Game Designer Wisdom for what to do with RCE’s cards: If you like the cards, use them." If you want to use the cards, there will be some information which is no longer relevant, but everything should be pretty much compatible (you'll need to recalculate initiatives, and gear descriptions have been tweaked - but does it matter if they're a touch off?).
Missions
Missions have a slightly different structure in PPE. It wouldn't break the game at all if you ran them as-written, though.

They are all expected to have secret objectives (not all did in RCE; the name has also changed from 'secret society missions').
PPE missions need a formal Mission Objective (one for each section of a published mission). This should generally be obvious, but you should define it for Upgrade Point purposes.
Some secret societies have been changed or removed, but they are all detailed in The Accomplice Book, a supplement of optional rules and setting details.
Achievements have been removed.

Setting
There are a ton of minor changes, and some fairly substantial ones. Canonically, any differences with RCE are due to Project Infinite Hole, and the Great Hotfix, which was planned well in advance and wasn't an emergency bodge job.
Changes not explained by the above events are few. Possible, "default" origin of Alpha Complex is now given. Knowledge of the Outdoors is not a treason. No "gotcha" from other players for knowing what a pig is. Exits from the Alpha Complex are not secret, just heavily guarded and won't open. The event that caused current situation is called Whoops and pre-Whoops technology now officially exists.
Misc.

Initiative is calculated differently
Hitting the difficulty exactly is a success (I thought it was in RCE too...)
Armour works a bit differently
When a PC Loses It their next clone has 4 Moxie (in RCE they didn't get their normal Moxie complement)
All equipment has Success and Treason effects (in RCE only experimental devices did)


Please comment if I missed anything significant.

The guns part took me by surprise the most. I wonder why they don't wabt bad shots anymore. I guess that's out of the scope of this question.

@Mołot it makes sense for one of the few games that encourages PvP to make sure every PC has some kind of chance to shoot the others - and they are genetically engineered to be troubleshooters, after all!

I guess the Famous Game Designers™ found it to be a pain point - it is, after all, kind of the default action. When in doubt, shoot a traitor (preferably in the back).

You'll get the bounty, but let's use the days left for more attention ;)

Thanks, I do feel like I must have missed something.

@aantia is it true that origin of the Alpha Complex is now explained and GM knows what's Outside? If so, I think I don't think I like that very much.

@Molot I think they do give a 'default' backstory for the setting, yes. I'll add a note about that to my answer. I'd do it now, but I read the 90s Cyberpunk crossover adventure (out of morbid curiosity) at the same time as the new core book, and I can't remember which timeline went with which...

@aantia I just received my books so I took liberty of adding a paragraph. Feel free to roll it back and assign me a treason star if you disagree.
